# Cannot import edu.stanford.nlp  - Stanford parser with jython problem

Tags: java, python, nlp, jython, stanford-nlp

Can someone help me out with the stanford parser from http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml?

I've only downloaded and unzipped the parser. 
I've also installed the jython fully but i cannot parse a sentence, it seems like i've installed some modules or something.
http://wiki.python.org/jython/InstallationInstructions

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('~/standford-parser-2010-11-30/stanford-parser-2011-11-30.jar')
>>> from java.io import CharArrayReader
>>> from edu.stanford.nlp import *
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: no module named edu
```

Is there more installation procedures other than unzipping it and importing it in jython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `sys.append` statement. The filename says `2011` when it should be `2010`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./stanford-parser-2010-11-30/stanford-parser-2010-11-30.jar')
from edu.stanford.nlp import *
print fsm
<java package edu.stanford.nlp.fsm 1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also look [here](http://blog.gnucom.cc/2010/using-the-stanford-parser-with-jython/) for some starting off example code.